# Function with vararg param clashes with another with Array param

Tags: kotlin

I'm overloading a function but I came across a problem

```
fun setNumbers(numbers: Array<Int>) {

}
```

clashes with

```
fun setNumbers(vararg numbers : Int) {

}
```

but none of them can deal with both

```
setAdapters(Array...)
setAdapters(varargs...)
```

is there any trick to make both of them not clash or accept both calls?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a *real* trick in the sense that you can't avoid the clash (without changing the name of the function), but you can call the `vararg` function as follows:

```kotlin
setNumbers(*intArrayOf(1, 2, 3))
```

Comment: Yeah this is the way the docs tell you to use an existing array: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs